# How to disable all links not in a list, using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a web application (using flask for backend).

In my backend, I retrieve the page source of a given url using selenium. I want to go through the page_source and disable all links whose href is not inside a list. Something like:

```
body = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.a:
    if not (link['href'] in link_list):
        link['href']=""
```

I am new to beautiful soup, so I am unsure about the syntax. I am using Beautiful soup 4

Comment: what do you mean disable? do you mean to say you do not want those tag in soup?

Comment: @KunduK I said disable links, not tags. I already figured it out (will write answer once I am done with code) if you're interested. Basically, I do find_all("a") then loop over the result and check if the href is in a list, if not then delete it and change the tag from a to span. The Ill just remove all span tags (using unwrap I think) from the html. This is so that the unneeded links dont keep the a tag style (underlined and highlighted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(c_body, 'lxml') #you can also use html.parser
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    if not (a['href'] in src_lst):   #src_list is a list of the urls you want to keep
        del a['href']
        a.name='span' #to avoid the style associated with links
soup.span.unwrap()    #to remove span tags and keep text only
c_body=str(soup)      #c_body will be displayed in an iframe using srccdoc
```

EDIT: Above code might break if there are no span tags, so this would be a better approach::

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(c_body, 'lxml')
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    if a.has_attr("href"):
       if not (a['href'] in src_lst):
            del a['href']
            a.name='span'

if len(soup.findAll('span')) > 0:
    soup.span.unwrap()
c_body=str(soup)
```